# I'm trying to receive a list with an array in RecyclerView and get error:

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I fetch below error

```
GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2020-11-19 19:32:10.000 20105-20105/com.example.popularmoviebycookies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.popularmoviebycookies, PID: 20105
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: please help me, if anyone knows the solution

Comment: can you please add your code as it says you are trying to access a recyclerview which isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your getting `NullPointerException` on the `recyclerView`. So it's most likely that you haven't initialized the `recyclerView` before performing any action on it.